# Make an animated series of pictures show

Tags: android, animation

I am trying, upon an imagebutton press, have the imagebutton play several pictures one of ahead of eachother to try and create a pseudo-gif. I have issues trying to play the other images. Im not sure how to create a delay between the pictures. Without waitTimer(), the image gets set to the last one in the list.

How do I create this animated image in this app?

```
public void waitTimer()
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("Test", "SLEEP 1000");
    }
}

public void hooplaanimation()
{
    ImageButton hp1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    hp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.h1);   
    waitTimer();
    hp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.h2);  
    waitTimer();
    hp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.h3);
    waitTimer();
    hp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.h4);
    waitTimer();
    hp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.h5);
    waitTimer();
    hp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.h6);
    waitTimer();
    hp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.h7);
    waitTimer();
    hp1.setImageResource(R.drawable.h8);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has two ways solve your problem:

1、use AnimationDrawable:[AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

2、please use these pictures generate a gif file,android write a GifView like this:
[GifView](https://code.google.com/p/gifview/)